# gRPC DEADLINE_EXCEEDED even that the server is up and

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, rpc, grpc

I have two microservices that communicate each other thru `gRPC`, `A` is the RPC client and `B` is the RPC server, both written in NodeJS using [grpc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grpc) NPM module.

Everything is working fine until, at some point in time, unexpectedly `A` stop being able to send requests to `B`, it fails because of a timeout (5s) and throw this error:

`Error: Deadline Exceeded`

Both microservices are Docker containers, run on AWS ECS and communicate thru AWS ELB (not ALB because it does not support HTTP2 and some other problems).

I tried to run `telnet` from `A` to the ELB of `B`, both from the EC2 instance and from the running ECS task (the Docker container itself) itself and it connected fine, but still, the NodeJS application in `A` cannot reach the NodeJS application in `B` using the gRPC connection.

The only way to solve it is to stop and start the ECS tasks and then `A` succeed to connect to `B` again (until the next unexpected time the same scenario is reproduced), but it's not a solution of course.

Do anyone faced with that kind of issue?

Comment: What was the conclusion for this issue? Did you (and how) resolve it? I am currently experiencing same issue. Deadling Exceeded for one unary grpc call, and then started to failing for every single after that one?

Comment: Facing the same issue, any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use unary or streaming API? Do you set any deadline?
gRPC deadline is per-stream, so in case of streaming when you set X milliseconds deadline, you'll get DEADLINE_EXCEEDED X milliseconds after you **opened** a stream (not send or receive any messages!). And you'll keep getting it forever for this stream, the only way to get rid of it is reopening a stream.

Comment: We're using both unary (for single models) and streaming (for collections) but the error i mentioned is received for the unary.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that I need to create both a new stub, but also re-create the connection after some errors in order to get it to reconnect. (Also running in ECS)